# Count Number of Hat-Trick

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result-set like this :

Result

L

W

W

W

L

L

W

W

W

I want to count the number of time W comes thrice continuously in SQL Server. Please help !

Comment: Please post the code you are having problems with.

Comment: Why would you do it in SQL? How large is the actual data table?

Comment: You can't with the data you specify.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Your problem definition requires an ordering.  You need to represent the order as a column in the data, say an id or creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are the LEAD/LAG functionality in SQL Server.

Here is a working sample, assume that 1 = win, 0 = loss.

```
CREATE TABLE WINLOSS (
  WINLOSSID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  WIN BIT NOT NULL
 );

INSERT INTO WINLOSS VALUES (1),(0),(1),(1),(1),(0),(1),(0),(1),(1),(1);


WITH TMP AS (
SELECT 
    WINLOSSID, 
    WIN, 
    LAG(WIN, 1) OVER  (ORDER BY WINLOSSID) LAG1,
    LAG(WIN, 2) OVER  (ORDER BY WINLOSSID) LAG2
FROM WINLOSS
)
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM TMP 
WHERE WIN = 1 AND LAG1 = 1 AND LAG2 = 1
```